# Adding ArrayList Objects to GridView in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gridview, arraylist

Hello I'm working on a project where I have to insert each object of type "Person" in an ArrayList of type "Person" to a Gridview in eclipse android. My intentions are to display a picture along with the Person's name (similar to Instagram). Here's what I have tried so far but this doesn't seem to work as I want it to and hard to understand.

Do yall have any better solutions?

```
ArrayList<Person> dbPersons = dop.getPersons(dop); //This is where I populate my list
int[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3
    };

            gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
            gridView.setAdapter(new function.CustomGrid(this, dbPersons, imageId));
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
```

My Person's class generally contains:

```
private String FName;
private String LName;
private String Biography;
```

Anyway I didn't want to bombard this post with my faulty code since I'm looking for a cleaner and better alternative. I just want to display the name as the gridview item's title and the picture below it and do the same for the rest of the objects in the arraylist. Could you please help me out guys :)

Comment: PLease check this 'http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html'

Comment: @Jedil i think your link is dead.. but Benildus, you want a code written for you based on your situation>?

Comment: @Elltz No buddy, just a sample that is similar to my situation will suffice. I can work my way through it then. I just want a sample where an arrayList containing objects are populated in a gridview :)

Comment: yeah, sorry, i was actually waiting on a mail from that email, but it never came, so idk, were you expecting me to rather mail? so mail me, and i'd expect pjayness as the username, k, no hard feelings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**your adapter**

```
 public class Benildus_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

ArrayList<Person> list; // your person arraylist
Context context; // the activity context
int resource; // this will be your xml file

public Benildus_Adapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<Person> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.list = objects;
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(list.size() == 0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return list.size();
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View child = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater(); // inflating your xml layout

    if (child == null) {            
        child = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.fname = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.fname); // fname is the reference to a textview
        holder.lname = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.lname); // in your xml layout file 
        holder.bio =(TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.bio); // you are inflating.etc
        child.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (RecordHolder) child.getTag();
    }

    final Person user = list.get(position); // you can remove the final modifieer.

    holder.fname.setText(user.getFName());      
    holder.lname.setText(user.getLName());
    holder.bio.setText(user.getBiography());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(user.getImage()); // if you use string then you download the image using
    // the string as url and set it to your imageview..
    return child;
}

static class RecordHolder {
    TextView fname,lname,bio;
    ImageView image;    
}


@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() { // you can remove this..
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    if(getCount() == 0){
        //show layout or something that notifies that no list is in..
    }else{
        // this is to make sure that you can call notifyDataSetChanged in any place and any thread
        new Handler(getContext().getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Benildus_Adapter.super.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

**your person class**

```
 public class Person {

private String FName;
private String LName;
private String Biography;
private Bitmap image; // add the image too to your class, you can store the url of the image 
// or save it using bitmap.. if you store the url then = String image; the load the image
// in the getview method.. any way you choose..
public String getFName() {
    return FName;
}
public void setFName(String fName) {
    FName = fName;
}
public String getLName() {
    return LName;
}
public void setLName(String lName) {
    LName = lName;
}
public String getBiography() {
    return Biography;
}
public void setBiography(String biography) {
    Biography = biography;
}
public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
}

}
```

**Edit** i just forget the set adapter..

```
 gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
 Benildus_Adapter bA = new Benildus_Adapter(this, R.layout.myxml,dbPersons);
 gridView.setAdapter(bA);
```

hope it helps, let me know