# Populate gridview from arraylist on android

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist

halllo,

im trying to populate the gridview from arraylist. i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471784/adding-arraylist-objects-to-gridview-in-android) and i follow it.

it work but the data is overwrite. that means the position is not good.
i am beginer in android, don't know how to fix it.

My code:
gridview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_CodeDest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_CodeCl"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_CodeCl"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/txt_code_dest" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_DateTampon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_CodeDest"
        android:text="@string/txt_date_tampon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_CodeCl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_DateTampon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_code_client" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and activity_liste_ordre_valide.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.soft8suivicolis.ListeOrdreValide" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView_Ordre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and listeordervalide.java

```
public class ListeOrdreValide extends ActionBarActivity {

    private GridView gridView_Ordre; 
    SQLController   dbcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_ordre_valide);

        gridView_Ordre=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_Ordre); 

         ArrayList<Pers_Ordre> oOder = new ArrayList<Pers_Ordre>();
          dbcon = new SQLController(this);

         dbcon.open();
         oOder = dbcon.ReadData();
         GridViewListAdapter TheAdapt = new GridViewListAdapter(this, R.layout.gridview_layout, oOder);

         gridView_Ordre.setAdapter(TheAdapt);

         dbcon.close();
    }
```

and of course my adapter class:

```
public class GridViewListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pers_Ordre>{

    ArrayList<Pers_Ordre> m_list; // your person arraylist
    Context m_context; // the activity context
    int m_resource; // this will be your xml file

    public GridViewListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Pers_Ordre> objects) {
        super(context, resource,  objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        m_list = objects;
        m_context = context;
        m_resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(m_list.size() == 0){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return m_list.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Pers_Ordre getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return m_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View child = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((ListeOrdreValide) m_context).getLayoutInflater(); // inflating your xml layout

        if (child == null) {            
            child = inflater.inflate(m_resource, parent, false);
            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.CodeCl = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.textView_CodeCl); // fname is the reference to a textview
            holder.CodeDest = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.textView_CodeDest); // in your xml layout file 
            holder.DateTampon =(TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.textView_DateTampon); // you are inflating.etc
            child.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (RecordHolder) child.getTag();
        }

        Pers_Ordre user = m_list.get(position); // you can remove the final modifieer.

        holder.CodeCl.setText(user.getLe_CodeClient());      
        holder.CodeDest.setText(user.getLe_CodeDest());
        holder.DateTampon.setText(user.getLe_Date());

        // the string as url and set it to your imageview..
        return child;
    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView CodeCl,CodeDest,DateTampon;

    }
```

Comment: Please explain `it work but the data is overwrite`

Comment: as u can see i have 3 column, normaly i should have 5 row, but i only got 1 row...all data is overwrite in 1 only row

Comment: What is size of `m_list` ?

Comment: the size of m_list is dynamic

Comment: @Override 
    public int getCount() { 
          return m_list.size();
    }